# Why error messages shouldn't end with a punctuation mark in Go?

Tags: go, error-handling, static-analysis

I have a problem with error text.

If I use the error message shown below, the editor's linter gives a warning like this: *"error strings should not end with punctuation or a newline"*:

```golang
return errors.New("Test!")
                       ^
```

The question is: why shouldn't I use punctuation? What is the real reason behind it?

Comment: That's the linter warning you I guess, not the go compiler - https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#ST1005

Comment: @muhammedikinci did you check the link? "Error strings should not be capitalized (unless beginning with > proper nouns or acronyms) or end with punctuation, since they are > usually printed following other context. That is, use > fmt.Errorf("something bad") not fmt.Errorf("Something bad"), so > that log.Printf("Reading %s: %v", filename, err) formats without a > spurious capital letter mid-message. "

Comment: @eis I checked https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#error-strings and thank you so much. I understand the reason now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Errors may be wrapped up the call stack and their messages may be concatenated before printing. If you add punctuation, the end result might be weird from a grammatical standpoint.

As the [link](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#error-strings) in the comment says:

> Error strings should not be capitalized (unless beginning with proper nouns or acronyms) **or end with punctuation**, since they are usually printed following other context.

As an example, consider the following program:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo()) // bar failed: baz failed!: some problem
}

func foo() error {
    err := bar()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %w", "bar failed", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func bar() error {
    err := baz()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %w", "baz failed!", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func baz() error {
    return errors.New("some problem")
}
```

Of course this example is contrived, but the point is that in a real-world scenario you don't know how your libraries — or users of your code — will format their errors. The issue is probably easier to demonstrate with the error package `"github.com/pkg/errors"`, where each call to `Wrap` results in a colon (`:`) separator when printing the message:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(errors.Wrap(errors.Wrap(errors.Wrap(errors.New("foo"), "bar"), "baz"), "quux"))
    // quux: baz: bar: foo 
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dxI2301IX1P